# JButton Stop Selection inside ActionPerformed

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

When I click a JButton its actionPerformed event is called, but the button has not been selected yet (I checked the ActionEvent source). Inside the actionPerformed event I want to check some values and decide whether or not the button should be selected, then select/deselect all inside the ActionPerformed event, something like below.

```
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ((JButton) e.getSource).isSelected(); //<=== returns false
            if(some values equal some things)
                ((JButton) e.getSource).setSelected(false);
        }
    });
```

I think I know how to do this inside the ItemListener but that only fires via programmatically selecting the button and I need it to be in the click listener.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: JButtons don't stay selected. Perhaps you want to use a JToggleButton, and yes an ItemListener.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I will probably end up using JToggleButton, but I'm curious as to why my JButtons have a border that makes it look like a JButton is/isn't selected.

Comment: @Quacksalot: See [`ButtonModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonModel.html).